# django models.ForeignKey behavior

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have 2  classes in `models.py` : `PRODUCTS` and `PARTS`.

```
class PRODUCTS (models.Model):
    productid = models.IntegerField(primary_key = True)
    ...

class PARTS(models.Model):
    partid= models.IntegerField(primary_key = True)
    productid = models.IntegerField(null = True, blank = True)
    ...
```

They are corespond with my two DB tables.

```
    CREATE TABLE `PRODUCTS` (
       `productid ` int(11) NOT NULL,
       ... )

    CREATE TABLE `PARTS` (
       `partid` int(11) NOT NULL,
       `productid ` int(11) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY  (`partid`),
        KEY `main_5cae8fa2` (`productid `),
        CONSTRAINT `productid_id_6ce77021aa` FOREIGN KEY (`productid `) REFERENCES `PRODUCTS` (`productid `)
       ... )
```

In django I need to get the parts of a specific product so I changed PARTS class to be:

```
class PARTS(models.Model):
    partid = models.IntegerField(primary_key = True)
    productid = models.ForeignKey(PRODUCTS, related_name = 'parts')
```

for example this I should be able to access the parts of product 100 like this:

```
products = PRODUCTS.objects.get(100)
x = products.parts
```

However this change causes a problem as django auto add `_id` to the column name meaning he is no longer looking for `productid` now he is looking for `productid_id`

> (1054, "Unknown column 'PARTS.productid_id' in 'field list'")

How can I disable the auto add of `_id` ? changing my column name will take hours there are so many places that insert/delete/update this table.

Comment: Don't use all-caps for your model class names. They're not constants. If you're using a legacy database with those table names, use the `Meta.db_table` parameter to specify the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually specify an column name for a model field with the [db_column](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#db-column) setting.

```
class PARTS(models.Model):
    partid = models.IntegerField(primary_key = True)
    productid = models.ForeignKey(PRODUCTS, related_name = 'parts', db_column='productid')
```

Comment: Yes, but the Django FK field should just be called `product`, not `productid`. It's not an ID.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman  in general the field should be called product in the class but in the DB it should be called product_id, with that pair the django auto add of _id is working smothly... but sometime you need to connect with django to an existsting DB that someone else created and you can not change the names he decided to use.

Comment: But that is exactly the point; use the `db_column` attribute to set the name of the db field to `productid`, but call the Django attribute itself `product`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman has a point. Normally you can access the id of the related object directly by using ```productid_id```. If the field and the column are both called ```productid```, it might not be possible to access that value directly anymore without getting the whole PRODUCT object from the DB. I would also recommend to call the field ```product```.